# Control the number of executors when running sql in spark thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-thriftserver

I have a spark thrift server,and users can submit spark sql to this server.

I would like I can control the number of executors that will be used to run user's sql.That is, I don't want executors will be given as many as possible(later submitted sql may have to wait)

I would ask whether this could be possible.

Comment: Difficult area, not well discussed imho.

Answer (score 0):

This controls max and min number of executors, but statically:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors
```

Dynamically, afaik, it is not possible.